# Como cambiar una fecha en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Quisiera saber como hago el update correcto para cambiar una fecha en específico en sql server, ya que el dato se encuentra en fecha "2023-01-**12** 00:00:00" y quiero indicar la fecha "2023-01-**15** 00:00:00"

lo estoy realizando así pero me indica error:

**Update** *[nombre de tabla]* **set** *nombre de la columna de fecha* = '2023-01-15 00:00:00' **where** *nombre de columna* = 2

(donde el 2 corresponde al dato específico al que le quiero cambiar la fecha)

y este es el error que me indica sql: *La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.*

Muchas gracias

Comment: debe ser por el formato de fecha del SQL, no hay mes 15, el formato de tu sql es YDM donde Y: 2023, D:15 y M:01

Comment: REvisa mi respuesta y comenta si te ayudo, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso debes hacer uso de [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) de esta forma:

```
UPDATE [nombre de tabla] 
SET [nombre de la columna de fecha] = CONVERT(datetime, '2023-01-15 00:00:00', 120)
WHERE [nombre de columna] = 2;
```

Para el formato que deseas:

```
 "2023-01-15 00:00:00"
```

debes usar él [estilo 120, revisa la tabla.](https://Jan%2015%202023%2012:00AM)

Revisa:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16